# VK API, как вернуть только нужные поля?

Tags: vkontakte-api

Не могу разобраться как правильно заполнить fields чтобы возвращались только нужные поля, а не всё.

`&fields=id` не работает :/

[Пример запроса.](https://vk.com/dev/wall.get?params%5Bowner_id%5D=6&params%5Bcount%5D=1&params%5Bfilter%5D=owner&params%5Bextended%5D=1&params%5Bfields%5D=id&params%5Bv%5D=5.122)

Comment: Скорее всего никак. А чем вам лишние поля помешали? Не используйте их да и всё

Comment: @andreymal понятно, спасибо, просто не хотелось лишнее грузить.

Comment: Хотя вообще можно попробовать извернуться через метод execute, но то такое

Comment: @andreymal лишние сложности не стоят того :)